# Prove that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |x-1/n|$ is differentiable on $x_0 \notin \{1, 1/2, 1/3, ... \}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |x-1/n|$ is differentiable on $x_0 \notin \{1, 1/2, 1/3, ...\}$

I think the relevant theorem is the term-by-term differentiation theorem which states:

Let $f_n$ be differentiable functions on A and assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n'(x)$ converges uniformly and that $\exists x_0 \in A$ where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges. Then
$f'(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n'(x)$ on A.

Here I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges for all R. So what I have left to show is that

1. Each $f_n$ is differentiable on $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, ...\}^c$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n'(x)$ converges uniformly on $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, ...\}^c$

But I'm stuck on showing 1. Once I write the limit definition I'm stuck.

Comment: Think about the function $f(x) = |x-a|$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it differentiable everywhere? Where is the critical point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $f_n(x)=2^{-n}\left(x-\frac1n\right)$ when $x>\frac1n$, and therefore $f_n'(x)=2^{-n}$ then. And $f_n(x)=-2^{-n}\left(x-\frac1n\right)$ when $x<\frac1n$, and therefore $f_n'(x)=-2^{-n}$ then.

This also proves that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\left(\forall x\in\Bbb R\setminus\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\}\right):|f_n'(x)|=2^{-n}$. Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Don't I have to show first that $f_n$ is differentiable before jumping to prove 2.?

Comment: Didn't I do just that?

Comment: Oh. I thought I had to use the limit definition to show that each $f_n$ is differentiable and then show $\sum_{1}^{\infty} f'_n(x)$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Do you think that I have answered your question?

Comment: Yea sorry I was just trying to see why $f$ is not differentiable at 1

Comment: But the question doesn't require you to prove that. Only to prove that it *is* differentiable at the points of $\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots,\right\}^\complement$.